# Can a Java ArrayList be empty and indexOf return an index of 0?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have the following segment of code in Java for Android:

```
int index = oldArray.indexOf(person);
if (index == -1) {
    Log.d("Tag", "TESI index == -1");
}
else {
    oldArray.remove(index);  <--- error is here
    newArray.add(person);
}
```

I got the following exception

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
at com.tesi.salus.PersonView.updatePerson(PersonView.java:406) [line 406 is the remove]
```

My question is how is that possible?

If I understand well, if `oldArray` is empty then `index` should be -1, not 0.

Or, am I missing something?

Thanks.

==================

Thanks for the answers.

I have only one thread.

`oldArray`is declared as:

```
public ArrayList oldArray<Person>;
```

And initialized below as:

```
oldArray = new ArrayList();
```

Comment: any other thread/asynctask/handler/timer could be touching your array at the same time?

Comment: @njzk2 if he was working with the array somewhere else in between that call wouldn't he get a ConcurrentModificationException on the remove call if he didn't instantiate a new instance of the ArrayList?

Comment: @zgc7009: no. ConcurrentModificationException only happens in cases where concurrent modification are explicitly checked, such as in Iterators.

Comment: @njzk2 thanks for the clarification, that was for my own interest not the OP :P

Comment: @zgc7009: for further details on that, look at the source from ArrayList iterator: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.Itr in particular, the `checkForComodification` method, which does the explicit verification

Comment: Also, post the declaration and definition of `oldArray`

Comment: You'll probably need to provide more contextual detail. It's unlikely list itself is broken in this way.

Comment: I belive `person` is null...

Answer (score 0):

if the object is null, it will find the index of null (which is zero in an empty list)

add a nullcheck and it should work